# Share part of monitor in screen sharing apps

Tags: macos, display, software-recommendation, video, screen-sharing

I have a Ultrawide monitor (21:9 aspect ratio 3440x1440px) and my colleagues find it annoying that when I share my screen on Zoom, Slack, Google Meet etc. it will get zoomed out so the wide aspect ratio will fit on their regular 16:9 monitors. In addition to that I often find that I like to keep something like a meeting agenda on the same screen without necessarily having it visible to meeting participants.

Does anyone know of a piece of software for Mac OS that will allow me to assign a portion of my screen (i.e. the 16:9 bit, so the first 2560px in width and all 1440px in height) and let me expose that to screen sharing apps as an additional "virtual monitor". With Quicktime screen recording you can select a portion of the screen to record. I'm looking for something similar that will allow me to pipe that portion of the screen into screen sharing applications.

Any ideas?

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but I think https://obsproject.com should do it

Comment: I know OBS, but did not think about using it for this task. I'll give it a shot, I think you might be right.

Answer (score 6):

Not exactly what you are asking for, but https://github.com/Stengo/DeskPad solves the same issue in a slightly different way. Hopefully this is helpful to you!

EDIT: to elaborate, the app creates a smaller virtual display that is mirrored in an application window. You can then share this new virtual display and work inside of it, but still use the rest of your ultrawide monitor for other things.

Comment: Hello, Stengo. This is considered a "link-only" answer. It would be helpful for future visitors to this question if you would [edit] in a summary of that page. Links can become broken or outdated so a summary would still provide the necessary information.

Comment: exactly what I need!
thanks for sharing and making it :)

Comment: Awesome exactly what I needed. Kudos to the developer of DeskPad